# Apache 2.4 config - 1 site but different folders

Tags: apache

Sorry if this has been asked before but I have tried searching and couldn't seem to find something related to my case. I'm a bit new in Apache so bear with me.

I have a website that was developed to have 2 different folders. Let us name the 2 as follows:

1. Front
2. Admin

All folders are inside of /var/www/html/MySite/

I want it to use only one port: 8080

How do I set it so that when I go to my browser and type DOMAIN:8080 I will be served the following

1. DOMAIN:8080 will be served from /Front/ folder
2. DOMAIN:8080/admin will be served from /Admin/ folder

Can this be done in one VirtualHost config  file?

I have tried in one file something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MySite/Front
<Directory /var/www/html/MySite/Front/>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

Alias /admin /var/www/html/MySite/Admin
<Directory /var/www/html/MySite/Admin/>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This only partially works. I can go to DOMAIN:8080 and I am shown the correct page. However when I go to DOMAIN:8080/admin/ I get the error,

> The requested URL /var/www/html/MySite/Admin/webroot/login was not found on this server.

Comment: You are looking for the `Alias` directive, not for virtual hosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: Ok. So how do I go about making my VirtualHost config file? Then where do I apply this Alias directive? Note the server is running on Apache2.4, Ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: You don't need virtual hosts, as mentioned above. If you want to define them because of other reasons not relevant here, then go. Inside the host definition you then place the `Alias` directive. The documentation I referenced shows easy examples for that...

Comment: now I'm even more confused. :D but thanks anyway for your help...